# angularJS AJAX postback method not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, ajax

Anyone please help me, I have created simple angularJS AJAX postback method.
below my HTML code.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function myCtrl1($scope) {
            $scope.ChkLogin = function () {
                alert('Hello...');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService1.asmx/Test",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        //alert('Success');
                        alert(msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        //alert('Failed');
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
    <div>
        <input type="button" name="btnTest" value="Test button" ng-click="ChkLogin()"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebService method :

```js
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "Hellow World";
        }
```

Upon clicking Test button, i get alert "Hello..." then failure alert msg, my webservice Test() has not been fired.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Specifiy Type = get

Change this - type: "GET",

Comment: I tried change type to "GET" im getting error msg alert "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your time, I had removed below line, now webservice method being fired.

```js
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```